# Blender Interface Glitching? Any ideas on how to fix, haven't come across this before

Tags: interface

[image][image]

Hi, Been working on a scene for a few days suddenly having issues with the interface glitching (see image below) lagging also occurring. Is this an issue I can fix within Blender or is it to do with having too much geometry/materials in the file?

Comment: That looks like something is seriously wrong. Perhaps an OpenGL error? At worst case a failing GPU (but doubtful since the "problem" is restricted to the viewport). Definitely make sure your graphics drivers are up to date, and possibly try with a fresh install of blender.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, I agree looks like there is definitely something seriously wrong - will do as you suggested!

Comment: Does the problem affect all of the different modes? Edit mode, sculpt mode, etc?

Comment: Does that scene from the image above occur all at once, or is that screenshot the result of panning around the viewport, and it's "keeping" the lines as you go (like a blurring and/or ghosting effect)? Also, what kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: @REMCodes it affects all tabs, different sorts of glitches on each

Comment: @ChristopherBennett its a result of panning around the viewport, I'm currently working with a MacBook Pro + Monitor so, Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB (I'm aware this is probably not technical enough, but I don't know too much about this) I have worked out if I delete the chair object all is fixed, so I believe its a problem within the chair model, may just have to backtrack to a previous version and work forward from there

Comment: ^ Added Image of Previously Rendered Scene for Material/Geometry Context